# Apache Log4j- Priority.WARN is deprecated - what to use instead?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am trying to log a message with `Apache Log4j`.

I was used to setting the priority-level by using `Priority.[level]`.

Example:

```java
Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class);
log.log(Priority.INFO, "Message")
```

My IDE now told me that `Priority.INFO` is deprecated. What should be used now instead? — while still in the `Log4j` framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the [Javadocs](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Priority.html), use Level class instead.

Example:

```java
logger.log(Level.INFO, "Log message" );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```java
logger.log(Level.toLevel("INFO"), "Processing Widgets");
```

Comment: Level.INFO would be a simpler solution. It doesn't require any casting